# There isn't fail reason when the transaction failed to execute with Web3.js 4.x

Tags: solidity, web3js

## Environment

OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Node: v18
Web3: 4.4.0

## Code Snippet

### Solidity

```
function _transfer(address from, address to, uint256 value) internal {
        if (from == address(0)) {
            revert ERC20InvalidSender(address(0));
        }
        if (to == address(0)) {
            revert ERC20InvalidReceiver(address(0));
        }
        _update(from, to, value);
    }
```

### Javascript

```
let web3 = new Web3('http://127.0.0.1:8545');
...
let signTx =
await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, accountPrivateKey);
let ret = await provider.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signTx.rawTransaction);
```

## Expectation

When the transaction reverts, the error contains detailed error information

## Result

No detail about the error

```
ContractExecutionError: Error happened while trying to execute a function inside a smart contract
    at Web3RequestManager._isReverted (/home/xxx/node_modules/web3-core/lib/commonjs/web3_request_manager.js:311:19)
    at Web3RequestManager._processJsonRpcResponse (/home/xxx/node_modules/web3-core/lib/commonjs/web3_request_manager.js:257:42)
    at Web3RequestManager.<anonymous> (/home/xxx/node_modules/web3-core/lib/commonjs/web3_request_manager.js:156:29)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/home/xxx/node_modules/web3-core/lib/commonjs/web3_request_manager.js:21:58)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  innerError: Eip838ExecutionError [CallError]: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
      at Blockchain.simulateTransaction (/home/xxx/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/1.js:2:85172) {
    innerError: undefined,
    code: -32000,
    receipt: undefined,
    data: '0x9c35377e0000000000000000000000003e014e5c311a7d6f652ca4f8bb016f4338a44118'
  },
  code: 310,
  receipt: undefined
}
```

## Question

How to get detailed information about transaction revertion?